# Persisting states amoung web pages

Tags: jquery, html, history.js, hashchange

I have 2 web pages(2 different pages on same domain saywww.mysite.a.html and  www.mysite.b.html )

In first page I have some check boxes; in second page I have some in input boxes.

In the first page I have a link that takes me to the second page.

Suppose I click some check box on the first page and navigate to second page.
(no data is saved at this moment in database).

From the second page let me press back button of the browser.
At this time whichever check boxes I check before I navigate to the second page should be kept as checked. if I press forward button at this state I should be going to second page   and the input boxes filled on second page should be filled as before.

How can I implement this is a web pages.

Can jquery.history.js or hashchange.js help me?

I don't think they can help me as I have 2 different pages.

Comment: Have you considered using [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, the easiest I would suggest would be to have 2 divs in the same form, where the first div contains the checkboxes, and the second contains the rest of the form fields.  Make the second div hidden when the page loads, and then when the user clicks on the first submit button, hide the first div and show the second.  Then when the user clicks on the second submit button, just submit the form which will have all the data from both div's form fields in it.

Alternatively you can try save the state in a cookie, or on the server side in session state, or you could render the second page with the data from the first page in 1 or more hidden inputs.

Comment: I have specifically said 2 page, NOT 2 divisions of same page.

Comment: So? I said that was the EASIEST, if you read further, I mention other ways you can achieve it.  2 divs in the same page is imho the simplest way, but using session state, cookies or hidden inputs are other ways which are not much more complicated.  If you want a clearer answer then you need to give more details.